# Can I assign a list of symbols to a list of elements in Guile?

Tags: scheme, guile

I'm writing some guile code that gets a list of a set length, and I need to define a variable for every element in the list.
Currently, I have to do something like this:

```
(define (foo l)
  (let ((e-1 (car l))
        (e-2 (cadr l))
        (e-2 (caddr l))
        ; ...
        (e-n (list-ref (- n 1)
                       l)))
    (compute)))
```

This gets *super* tedious. Is there anyway I can do something like this instead?

```
(define (foo l)
  (symbol-def e-1 e-2 e-3 e-4 e-n l)
  (compute))
```

**Edit:** Made question more guile-specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is scheme's equivalent of tuple unpacking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220515/what-is-schemes-equivalent-of-tuple-unpacking)

Answer (score 0):

Guile-specific, I've found the [ice-9 match module](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), which has the following form:

```
(match lst
    ((pattern) expr))
```

Example:

```
(use-modules (ice-9 match))

(let ((l '(test foo bar)))
  (match l
    ((head second third)
     second)))

; returns `foo`
```

Comment: It is not particularly guile-specific, since guile uses Alex Shinn's portable match implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple values is one way to bind the elements of a list of known length to variables:

```lisp
;;; Using SRFI-8 receive syntax
(use-modules (ice-9 receive))
(define (foo l)
  (receive (e-1 e-2 e-3 e-4) (apply values l)
    (format #t "~S~%~S~%~S~%~S~%" e-1 e-2 e-3 e-4)))
(foo '(1 2 3 4))

;;; Using SRFI-11 let-values syntax
(use-modules (srfi srfi-11))
(define (foo2 l)
  (let-values (((e-1 e-2 e-3 e-4) (apply values l)))
    (format #t "~S~%~S~%~S~%~S~%" e-1 e-2 e-3 e-4)))
(foo2 '(a b c d))

;;; Using R5RS call-with-values
(define (foo3 l)
  (call-with-values
    (lambda () (apply values l))
    (lambda (e-1 e-2 e-3 e-4)
      (format #t "~S~%~S~%~S~%~S~%" e-1 e-2 e-3 e-4))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing worth mentioning is define-values

```
(define (bar l)
  (define-values (a b c d) (apply values l))
  (compute a b c d))
```